# Is there a way to disable vim's swap file warning?

Tags: git, vim

Whenever I run

```
git commit --amend
```

and I think some other commands also

I get a warning from vim before I edit the commit message, that says something like:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/Desktop/code/web/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
```

I always ignore the warning, and just write my commit message and save the file. Is there a way I can disable this warning permanently?

Comment: Just delete the swap file...

Comment: Deleting the swap file would stop the warning from coming up.

Comment: ah thank you! didn't realize this was the case, problem solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the swap file gets rid of the warning:

```
rm ~/Desktop/code/web/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
" Don't let Vim's "Found a swap file" message block input
set shortmess=A
```

And never worry about the annoying swapfile message again!

Comment: is I do this, can I still recover non-saved progress by the swp if there is the "(R) recover" option?

Comment: Not working for MacVim 8.2.2164 (169). Still get the popup "Swap file already exists".

Answer (score 1):

if you are editing the files with vim/gvim editor, then set the below command in your .vimrc/.gvimrc file to avoid the generation of swap files

```
set noswapfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete the offending swap file from the prompt inside Vim, when it happens. You'll see something like this:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/.vim/tmp/test.txt.swp"
          owned by: jim   dated: Mon Nov 21 00:54:03 2016
         [cannot be read]
While opening file "test.txt"
             dated: Mon Nov 21 00:53:38 2016

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r test.txt"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/Users/jim/.vim/tmp/test.txt.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "~/.vim/tmp/test.txt.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

If you hit `D` here, it will delete the swap file that caused the error message, and you won't see it again for that one file. You can then write your file again, and you won't get the error.

Not directly related to your question, but something you may want to consider is changing the `directory` option so that swap files aren't created in the same directory as the file you're editing.  I use:

```
set directory=~/.vim/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
```

Which will try using those directories, in order. This helps keep swap files in one place, so it's easier to delete them all at once, if Vim crashes while you have a bunch of files open:

```
rm ~/.vim/tmp/*
```

It also prevents swap files from ending up in your Git tree, without worrying about `.gitignore`.